# In Python Create A Numeric Date/Time Representation

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

How in Python *(3.4)*, how can I create a **numeric date time** representation? It will be used as a 'score' and [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/ZRANGEBYSCORE)* query on Redis?

More details: I'm using Redis and Python. I need to represent dates and time as numbers to allow me to query a *Sorted Set*. The set would be keyed on an ID. The score would be the numeric date time representation.

I've read this is possible using `ZRANGEBYSCORE` to get article IDs within a date range, but I'm unable to find any examples on how to create a numeric date time representation in Python that I can use as the score! Would you use something like an epoch?

Comment: Um... like a standard timestamp?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, exactly, but it would need to allow me to for example say, fetch all ids in the last x days etc

Comment: Say I have a date like ``2016-04-15T14:43:44.269Z``,  I need this to be a numeric representation somehow. This way, I could get all keys within a range etc @TigerhawkT3

Comment: If you need numbers (like `int` or `float`), that's what timestamps are for. If you want to do calculations, it's much easier with `datetime`, although that's a full object rather than a single number.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Would you use something like an epoch?

Comment: Is the time stamp in Python an epoch  using UTC then? If so this would work and maybe I'm overthinking it! @TigerhawkT3

Comment: Timestamps are calculated based on an epoch. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)).

Comment: Ok, that will work then! @TigerhawkT3 Can I thank you by accepting an answer?

Comment: I'm assuming  ``timestamp = int(time.time())`` give a Unix timestamp as Redis requires it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `time` module has a `time()` function that produces a localized Unix-style timestamp.

```
>>> import time
>>> int(time.time())
1460845456
```

Note again that this is localized - it is based on the local time and is not timezone-aware.

If you want to do calculations, the `datetime` module is very useful:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 16, 15, 26, 14, 657718)
>>> datetime.datetime.now().day
16
>>> datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=3)
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 13, 15, 26, 43, 769385)
```

You can also convert between these formats:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 16, 15, 28, 6, 29099)
>>> datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
1460845739.061133
```